# PHP - Search and Replace content in between

Tags: php, regex, replace

I want to search for a particular string/pattern and remove it. The pattern starts off with:

```
<!DOCTYPE
```

...and ends with:

```
]>
```

I want to remove it, and anything else in-between. Also it should not be case sensitive.

I have tried the `str_replace()` function but it does not remove the in between content.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please show what you've tried...

Comment: Does the string span multiple lines?

Comment: @Arvin: Yes the string spans multiple lines.

Comment: @Stefan: I tried "str_replace( "<!DOCTYPE" , "", $txt )" and "str_replace( "]>" , "", $txt )" to remove the contents, but that still left the in-between content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a use case for preg_replace. Regular expressions are our friends:

```
$txt = preg_replace("#<!DOCTYPE(.*?)\]>#sim", "", $txt);
```

The `(.*?)` here matches the shortest possible string within. And `""` is the replacement.

But are you sure that `]>` is the correct string to look for as terminator?

Comment: Thanks for the help Mario. Basically I am grabbing an XML file that contains "<!DOCTYPE ...." which contains "<!ELEMENT ..." and "<!ATTLIST ...". The tag then ends with "]>". I want to strip all of that out of my XML file.

Comment: @MercuryTerminal: Ah okay. I was unsure if it was for a DTD or just a HTML DOCTYPE declaration. -- Anyway, if you've got time and want to learn more about the usefulness of regexps, try http://regular-expressions.info/ or one of the nice tools here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world

Comment: Thanks. Reading up on it now. =)